# Creating my nuget package

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget-package, class-library

I created a new and very simple (ASP.NET 5) Class Library project which is supposed to generate a nuget package.

It compiles fine but the publish option is grayed out. How do I created my own package from this project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- From VS, make sure "Produce outputs on build is checked"
- From command line: run `dnu pack` in your project folder

Comment: For some reason it was not working on that project. Killed it and started a new project and now it's working fine. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @victor-hurdugaci Is there yet any documentation for this with dotnet cli?

Comment: `dotnet pack` does the same as `dnu pack` :)